# Check if input is correct/incorrect and color the input field

Tags: javascript

I have to make a patientsform (I did it with a table) and ask a few personal questions. For example: a patientsnumber. After somebody filled in their number, I have to check (in Javascript) if the number contains exactually 8 numbers. When it contains 8 numbers, the input field becomes green, and when the input is incorrect, it should give a message (i.e. "Give a patientsnumber with 8 numbers.") and the input field should be red. 
Here are two ways a tried to get the right code, but both did not work. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you in advanced!

```
 function checkpnummer() {
    var pnummer = $('#pnummer').val; 
    if(pnummer != /^([0-9]a{8})$/) {
      pnummer.style.color = "#CD5C5C";
      alert("Vul een patientnummer in dat bestaat uit 8 cijfers.");
    }

    else {
      pnummer.style.color = "#00FA9A";
      $('#pnummer').focusout(pnummer);   
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not how you match strings with a regex. Also, `val` is a function. You are comparing a function to a regex object. You need to _match_ a _string_ instead.

Comment: The syntax of accessing the style.color is also incorrect.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com), [MDN: Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @Xufox: is it better to use the method:                                                       
 var pnummer = document.getElementsById("pnummer");

Comment: @Maaike This method doesn’t exist, it’s `document.getElementById`. It’s up to you whether to use jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using jquery so here is the correct jquery solution-

```
function checkpnummer() {
 if(!$('#pnummer').val().match(/^\d{8}$/)) {
  $('#pnummer').css({"background-color": "#CD5C5C"});
  alert("Vul een patientnummer in dat bestaat uit 8 cijfers.");
 }
 else {
  $("#pnummer").css("background-color", "#00FA9A");
  $("#pnummer").focusout();
 }
}
```

I have pointed out few mistakes in your code -

- Incorrect use of `val()` method
- Incorrect regular expression
- Incorrect way to alter css of an element ( use `$("element").css("property": "value")` )
- Incorrect way to match regular expression ( use `match()` method )

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you @anu-007! Unfortunately my code is still not working. I have less experience with jquery, could you maybe tell me more about how to start ($(function)...) my jquery script?

Comment: you just have to call checkpnummer() function. For this I would suggest to use this code in your html   `<button onclick="checkpnummer()">submit</button>`  it is invoking checkpnummer() function when the button is clicked.

Comment: It's not allowed to use buttons to check if the input is correct.. Only the regular expression should be check with the input. When the input is correct , the input field gets the color green and otherwise the color red. This is a code I used for css, but I couldn't find a code to link this code with html (input fields) and js(regular expression) so I didn't use it.                           
         input:invalid {
         background-color: #ffdddd;
         }
         input:valid {
         background-color: #ddffdd; }

Comment: ok then you may use ` onblur="checkpnummer()"` in your input tag. something like this `<input type="text" id="pnummer" onblur="checkpnummer()">`

Answer (score 0):

`var pnummer = document.getElementById("pnummer").value` and try this code `if(pnummer.match(/^([0-9]a{8})$/)) { //true } else { //false }` the string match is 0aaaaaaaa, 1aaaaaaaa etc